# merge 2 arrays based on similar value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

hello so this is my array for example:

```
 [0] => Array
( 
    [id] => 10
    [count] => 10     
)

[1] => Array
    (   
        [id] => 10      
        [count] => 20     
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10
        [count] => 30     
    )
```

I would like to merge these 3 arrays into 1 by id to this format :
array(id=>'10' , count => ('10' ,'20', '30') )
I have multiple ids and each one i want to return a string that has the count in this format "10,20,30,etc.." any ideas please ?

Comment: So what have you tried?  What problems are you having in implementing something?  Have you at least tried "brute" force looping approach?

Comment: I am stuck at the very beginning which is selecting the arrays that have the same id value. Once I select the arrays with same ID value I can put the final array together ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If U are bruteforcing it U can do something like this :

```
<?php
    $source = [
        [
            'id'    => 10,
            'count' => 1,
        ],
        [
            'id'    => 15,
            'count' => 2,
        ],
        [
            'id'    => 10,
            'count' => 3,
        ],
        [
            'id'    => 12,
            'count' => 4,
        ],
        [
            'id'    => 10,
            'count' => 5,
        ],
    ];
    $output = [];
    foreach($source as $arr) {
        if (!isset($output[$arr['id']])) $output[$arr['id']] = '';
        $output[$arr['id']] .= $arr['count'].',';
    }   
    var_dump($output);
```

Only thing here is that there is an extra `,` at the end.
[running example](http://ideone.com/XYT8lb)

Comment: what are you trying there with `,` op wants an array with count values ^^

Comment: OP stated he wanted a string... `i want to return a string that has the count in this format "10,20,30,etc.."`

Comment: oh, sorry, guess this passed my view ^^

Comment: this looks like what I am trying to do thanks !

Comment: This does not produce what you requested. Please be more clear in what you actually want before asking your questions.

Comment: how do you know Funk ? :) it does work great I implemented it and many thanks to @DarkBee life saver!

Answer (score 0):

without searching i would try some like this

```
foreach($source as $s){
    $dest[$s['id']]['count'][] = $s['count']; 
}
```

after this you could make this to string by `implode(',', $array);`

guess there are better ways than this :)

Answer (score 0):

This returns exactly what was requested array(id=>'10' , count => ('10' ,'20', '30') )

```
foreach($array as $x){
$newarray[$x["id"]][]=$x["count"];
}
foreach($newarray as $id=>$count){
$c=implode(",",$count);
$newnewarray[]=array("id"=>$id,"count"=>"($c)");  
}
print_r($newnewarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code without the trailing ,

```
$result = array();

foreach($source as $s){
    if(!isset($result[$s['id']]))
        $result[$s['id']] = $s['count'];
    else
        $result[$s['id']] .= ',' . $s['count'];
}
var_dump($result);
```